# How to lock focus on a text input box so that it is always active?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a checkout screen that will go on a touchscreen that is attached to a barcode scanner, no other mouse or keyboard will be accessible from the user side. The scanner will scan into a text input box that I need to always be highlighted and active, even if someone accidentally clicks outside it, without them having to click inside the text input again to refocus it.

I have the input text box that the barcode will scan into focused and active upon load with the jquery below, but is there a solution to make that always focused, even when you click or touch outside of the input field? This is all I have so far to make it focus on load:

```
$('input[name="patronid"]').focus();
```

So even though the page has other elements like a footer and scrolling ad space, the only element I want to ever focus on is the input field with the text box and button to submit the barcode when they scan. Hope someone can help!

Comment: Bind a `focus` event handler to `document` that checks if the event target has that name. If not, call that line of code.

Comment: You can set the $(document).on('focus', function(event)) to refocus on the input, however, there has to be another, better way to do this than disabling the focus change - how are you putting the text in the textbox?  why not set the text value using `$('input[name="patronid"]').val(<barcode value>)`?

Comment: An application for a scanner should probably not be written as a web application...

Comment: @Jeff, the barcode will be put directly into the textbox from the scanner hooked up to the touchscreen. I will set the text value to barcode thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There's a `blur` event whenever a component *loses* focus. Just grab focus again whenever you get a blur event for this input.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('input[name="patronid"]').focus();

$('input[name="patronid"]').blur(function(){
  $('input[name="patronid"]').focus();
});

$('button').click(function(){
  console.log('click detected - returning now to input field');
  console.log('More can be done in here, if required');
  //Turn off the .blur if needed
  $('input[name="patronid"]').off('blur');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input name="patronid" />
<button>Ok 2 Click</button>
```